# How to raise error deep in an iteration chain without turning the whole thing into nested for loops?

Tags: exception, rust, iterator

I have a nested `Vec` structure where I need to convert the deepest `Vec` into a tuple. Consider the following example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let input = vec![vec![vec![vec![1.0, 2.0]]]];
    let output: Vec<Vec<Vec<(f64, f64)>>> = input
        .iter()
        .map(|r1| {
            r1.iter()
                .map(|r2| r2.iter().map(|r3| (r3[0], r3[1])).collect())
                .collect()
        })
        .collect();
}
```

I make the assumption that there are at least two values in the deepest vector, but if there aren't, then this code will fail. I'd like to have `main` return an error to indicate this, but because the indexing is in the iterator chain, I cannot simply use `?` or return an error.

I'd like to *not* turn this whole thing into for loops. Assuming this, what are my options and what is idiomatic?

Comment: Did you read this? https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/iter_result.html#fail-the-entire-operation-with-collect

Comment: a vec of vec of vec is the worst thing to do, also call the 3 stars programmers in C. you should use ndarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Result<FromIterator<Item = T>, E>` implements `FromIterator<Result<T, E>>`. You can collect an iterator of `Result`s into a `Result` of a collection and use `?` on the `Result`.

Moreover, since it is `FromIterator`, you can recursively collect the result, directly collecting an iterator of `Result`s into a `Result` of `Vec`.

```
fn main() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    let input = vec![vec![vec![vec![1.0, 2.0]]]];
    let output: Vec<Vec<Vec<(f64, f64)>>> = input
        .iter()
        .map(|r1| {
            r1.iter()
                .map(|r2| {
                    r2.iter()
                        .map(|r3| {
                            if r3.len() >= 2 {
                                Ok((r3[0], r3[1]))
                            } else {
                                Err("Bad")
                            }
                        })
                        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, &str>>()
                })
                .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, &str>>()
        })
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, &str>>()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=396044c9339799267f6ae5c86cbc9efa)

Comment: By the way, after I passed this to `rustfmt`, it looks even more spaghetti than using three for loops.